# Mysql server won't start, I've tried everything

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to start MAMP for well over 2 hours it just won't start. Here is a pic of what I mean.

[image: Mysql server won't start]

I've already tried deleting ib_logfiles and ibdata file as well, still MAMP just hangs in there, this has happened before and usually restarting the program solves the issue but not now. What can I do?

This is the error logged I found on mysql_error_log.err file

```
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.34 started; log sequence number 156022943
C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: File '.\mysql-bin.000181' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [ERROR] Failed to open log (file '.\mysql-bin.000181', errno 2)
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [ERROR] Could not open log file
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Binlog end
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2018-05-30 12:57:25 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 156022953
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2018-05-30 12:57:27 10840 [Note] C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the path for mysql binary dependencies is not set up correctly, since it is complaining that it can't find `.\mysql-bin.000181`...

does the binary exist at that path? (apparently not..)
Try locating it and / or reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue I had to uninstall MAMP completely and installed it again, you must save the directory PathTo/MAMP/db/mysql to save your databases and after you install MAMP again you just replace the folder and everything works back to normal